# LSI RAID not synchronizing

Tags: raid, lsi

There is a HS22 Blade with RAID. I removed one of the mirrored disk, and used it for other, but now I'm inserting it back, but it doesn't sync from the working disk.

`cfggen` shows the following:

```
cfggen_linux_i686_x86-64/cfggen 0 display
LSI Logic IR Configuration Utility 2.06.00
Read configuration has been initiated for controller 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Controller information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Controller type                         : SAS1064E
  BIOS version                            : 6.30.00.00
  Firmware version                        : 1.30.05.00
  Channel description                     : 1 Serial Attached SCSI
  Initiator ID                            : 112
  Maximum physical devices                : 62
  Concurrent commands supported           : 277
  Slot                                    : 0
  Bus                                     : 11
  Device                                  : 0
  Function                                : 0
  RAID Support                            : Yes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IR Volume information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IR volume 1
  Volume ID                               : 1
  Status of volume                        : Degraded (DGD)
  RAID level                              : 1
  Size (in MB)                            : 285148
  Physical hard disks (Target ID)         : 3 255
IR volume 2
  Volume ID                               : 132
  Status of volume                        : Inactive, Okay (OKY)
  RAID level                              : 1
  Size (in MB)                            : 285148
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical device information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initiator at ID #112
Target on ID #2
  Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 1
  Connector ID                            : 1
  Target ID                               : 2
  State                                   : Online (ONL)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 286102/585937500
  Manufacturer                            : IBM-ESXS
  Model Number                            : CBRCA300C3ETS0
  Firmware Revision                       : C370
  Serial No                               :
  Drive Type                              : SAS
  Protocol                                : SAS
Target on ID #3
  Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 0
  Connector ID                            : 0
  Target ID                               : 3
  State                                   : Online (ONL)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 286102/585937500
  Manufacturer                            : IBM-ESXS
  Model Number                            : CBRCA300C3ETS0
  Firmware Revision                       : C370
  Serial No                               :         PDVTTZME
  Drive Type                              : SAS
  Protocol                                : SAS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enclosure information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enclosure#                                : 1
  Logical ID                              : 088306cc:5005076b
  Numslots                                : 4
  StartSlot                               : 0
  Start TargetID                          : 0
  Start Bus                               : 0
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

if I got it you detached 1 disk from a RAID1, then it was switched on in an other server and eventually introduced back into the original server: if so the controller could be confused on which is the primary disk that have to mirrored on the other.

can you initialize again the disk that's supposed to receive the data ? this will erase the RAID information from that disk.